# Dealing with multiple references in CloudKit & Connecting CloudKit to an iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, cloudkit

I have an SQLite database on an iOS app. It was a simple table before which was syncing with iCloud. Now, new features are being added to the app and new tables are being added. This new table affect just one part of the app - Measurements saving. Now, each measurement has a measurementTemplate, each measurementTemplate is present in a page and contains an associated image guide. I'm looking for the best way to send these measurements to iCloud and fetch them back. Two of the record types on the CloudKit dashboard also contain double references. How do I work with double references? I have been on this issue for over 3 weeks without any progress.

I don't know how to save these measurements in CloudKit. The previous one done by the previous dev was straightforward, but considering the fact that a measurement has a reference to a measurement template which has an associated image guide. It's all interwoven and I'm confused. I'm new to SQLite and CloudKit.

This is an inherited codebase, the previous developer already started the work but didn't complete it yet.

Comment: "I'm looking for the best way to send these measurements to iCloud and fetch them back."  Your question is way too broad.

Comment: @ElTomato I don't know how to save these measurements in CloudKit. The previous one done by the previous dev was straightforward, but considering the fact that a measurement has a reference to a measurement template which has an associated image guide. It's all interwoven and I'm confused. I'm new to SQLite and CloudKit

Comment: From what it sounds like you have a design flaw in your data model or an architectural issue. I'm not sure why you'd ever need to send a piece of data then "send it back" all you would really need is successful response. Plus when you have 'double references' you introduce lots of complexity. I'd suggest using a tool like 'miro' to draw out your data model and untangle it. You may want to consider introducing an api layer to manage syncing up your models as well.

Comment: I will look into that. Thanks @BrooksDuBois